# Firebase functions: if value exists, act then delete

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to validate my user email adress via a link sent by mail on sign up.
When the user signs up I create a ref to its uid in a temp table and send a mail with a link to activate his account.
this link calls my firebase cloud function where i check if the value passed in pararmeter exists in the temp table, if so I activate the associated account and then delete the record on temp table.

What I have so far :

```
exports.confirmMail = (data) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/Email-Verifications/${data.uid}`).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        let uid = snapshot.val().userId;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { emailVerified : true })
            .then(()=>{
                admin.database().ref(`/Email-Verifications/${data.uid}`).remove()
                .then(()=>{
                    console.log('email verified');
                    return 'Ok';
                })
                .catch(()=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    return error;                    
                })
            })
        })        
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    })
}
```

This works (according to logs in firebase console) but on my front end I get an empty object back, so no way to know if the process actually worked.

Iam lost with the promise returns, I had to change a .then by the `return new Promise (...)` to remove a 'maximum callstack size exceeded' error I had.

On the front I call it with :

```
    verifMail(uid){
    console.log('fetching on uid : ' + uid);
    var func = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('confirmMail');
        console.log(func);
        func({ uid : uid })
    .then((responseValue)=> {
        console.log(responseValue);
        this.setState({ isProcessDone : true});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: So in firebase console you get the log `email verified` from your function? Did you tried on the frontend without `console.log(func)`?

Comment: Exactly, and same result without the log

Comment: And you initialized your firebase project in your frontend? And also your function is running in `us-central1`?

Comment: Yes, all this is done, this is the only function with inner promises i have, others work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your cloud functions like this:

```
exports.confirmMail = (data) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/Email-Verifications/${data.uid}`).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        let uid = snapshot.val().userId;
        return admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { emailVerified : true })
            .then((userRecord)=>{
                return admin.database().ref(`/Email-Verifications/${userRecord.uid}`).set(null)
                .then(()=>{
                    console.log('email verified');
                    return { uid: uid };
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    return error;                    
                })
            })
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    })
}
```

Your return from your last `.then()` should include the data you want to get on your frontend.

But I'm not sure I forgot anything because of the missing IDE that points out my syntax errors.

Comment: mhhh ... the result is different but still not that.
In my console I get a `data:null` where earlier I had `data:{}`, and the function executes correctly again (seen in logs)

Comment: Thank you but still no luck same result as before, i see the mail is verified in the logs but the return value in the front is still `data:null`

Comment: OK, worked it out! there was just a return missing on your last edit before the last .then.
Now it works perfectly thanks a lot!